# Multiple self referenced ForeignKey relationship fields in Django model

Tags: django

Which way should I create multiple self referenced ForeignKey fields in Django model? My current Model looks like:

```
class WordCoreModel(models.Model, BaseModel):
    word_core = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    word_russian_typed = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)
    word_english_typed = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)

    homonym = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="core_words",
        related_query_name='homonym')
    synonym = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="core_words",
        related_query_name='synonym')
    antonym = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="core_words",
        related_query_name='antonym')

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['word_core'])]
        verbose_name = 'Core Word'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Core Words'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word_core
```

Please give me some best-practices examples. I searched a lot for different solutions. I don’t find examples when there are several fields in the model.

I especially need help in determining `related_name` and `related_query_name` in this case.

Comment: The related name is simply the name of the relation in reverse. But I guess you here need a `ManyToManyField` anyway, unless of course, each word has only *one* homonym, synonym, antonym, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you need a `ForeignKey` here in the first place, since that would mean that a `WordCoreModel` has zero or one `homonym`s, zero or one `synonym`s, zero or one `antonym`s in one direction, and many in the other direction.

You likely want to use a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) here. That means that a word can have multiple homonyms, synonyms and antonyms, like:

```
class WordCoreModel(models.Model, BaseModel):
    word_core = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', db_index=True)
    word_russian_typed = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    word_english_typed = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)

    homonyms = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    synonyms = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    antonyms = models.ManyToManyField('self')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Core Word'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Core Words'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word_core
```

By default, a `ManyToManyField` that refers to itself is *symmetrical*. That means that if `a` is a synonym of `b`, then `b` is a synonym of `a`. It also means that you do not need `related_names` here: there is no direction in the relation, so a `WordCoreModel` has only relations named `homonyms`, `synonyms` and `antonyms`.